# Changing legend shape in ggpol::geom_parliament

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the key legend shape to circle (shape 21), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```r
library(ggpol)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- data.frame(Type = c("R"), value = c(100))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_parliament(aes(seats = value, fill = Type))
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I have tried with guides, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: The guide line from the manual `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))` , which had no impact.

Comment: `library(ggpol) library(ggplot2) df <- data.frame(Type = c("R"), value = c(100)) ggplot(df) +    geom_parliament(aes(seats = value, fill =  Type))` - a smaller script, still showing the same behaviour

Comment: thanks @Isaiah for the good example which I have incorporated into the question and my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is desired behaviour (this might or might not have been a deliberate design decision by the author of this Geom), and might warrant an issue report to the package maintainer. `ggpol::GeomParliament` uses `rectGrob` to draw the legend key (you can see that by looking at `GeomParliament$draw_key`). You can override this by first defining the correct `draw_key` function (using the `key_glyph` argument in the geom) and then override the aesthetics in `guides`.

```r
library(ggpol)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- data.frame(Type = c("R"), value = c(100))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_parliament(aes(seats = value, fill = Type), key_glyph = "point") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10, shape = 21)))
#> Warning: Using the `size` aesthetic in this geom was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` in the `default_aes` field and elsewhere instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>